# GraphQL pagination partial response with error array

Tags: error-handling, graphql, graphql-js, dataloader

I have a query like below

```
query {
    heroes {
        node {
            name
        }
        endCursor
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand how GraphQL can handle the error handling and return partial response. I looked at https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/issues/169 and tried to create a resolver like below;

```
{
    Query: {
        heroes: async (_) => {
            const heroesData = await loadHeroesFromDataWarehouse();
            return {
                endCursor: heroesData.endCursor;
                node: heroesData.map(h => h.name === 'hulk' ? new ApolloError('Hulk is too powerful') : h)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping it would resolve something like below;

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Hulk is too powerful",
      "path": [
        "heroes", "1"
      ],
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "heroes": [
      {
        "name": "spiderman"
      },
      null,
      {
        "name": "ironman"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but it is completely failing making the `heroes` itself `null` like below;

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Hulk is too powerful",
      "path": [
        "heroes"
      ],
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "heroes": null
  }
}
```

How can I make resolver to return me the desired partial response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, basically we need a resolver to resolve the edge model itself;

```
{
    Query: {
        heroes: (_) => loadHeroesFromDataWarehouse()
    },
    HeroesEdge {
        node: async (hero) => hero.name === 'hulk' ? new ApolloError('Hulk is too powerful') : hero
    }
}
```